# How to allow CORS in router functions?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I'm building a web application rest controller using Spring 5 router functions to map requests.

```java
@RestController
public class AdminRest {

public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions
            .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/admin/organizations"), this::getOrganizations);
}
}
```

Having Angular 4 project acts as a consumer for the rest controller.

```
public getOrganizations(): Observable<OrganizationsList> {
return this.http.get(this.getOrganizationsUrl)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
 }
```

Which return this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip:port/admin/organizations. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. }

How can I allow CORS in Spring 5 router function?

Comment: you can use `.OPTIONS` not just `.GET` as CORS works by sending an Options Request first to get the headers with permissions in them.

Comment: @MartinBarker - Didn't work
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip:port/admin/organizations. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: so you have a code error preventing it from responding to the Options Request use something like ARC plugin for chrome and debug it that way see what error your server is sending back if you can, if not turn on error logging on your server and go log trawling

Answer (score 0):

Could you annotate as

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
```

Please see [Spring CORS documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-cors) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Adding a configuration file did the trick for me

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/admin/organizations")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```